# libjson parses integers incorrectly

Tags: c++, c, json

I am trying to parse following JSON data (created with JSON.stringify). I am using libJSON 7. My code follows:

```
wstring jsonstr = _T("{\"Id\":0,\"Note\":\"\",\"Username\":\"user\",\"Password\":\"pass\",\"Enabled\":true,\"ProfileId\":\"\",\"UserAgent\":\"\",\"LastUsage\":0,\"Failures\":0,\"Abuses\":0}");
JSONNode jsondata = libjson::parse(jsonstr);
auto i = jsondata.begin();
auto num = i->as_float();
int idIsNan = _isnan(num);// Nonzero here
```

Now I expect that num == (double)0, however, it equals 1.#QNAN00000000000 instead. Does anyone know how to bypass this bug?
Also if I use as_int instead of as_float, it parses data correctly; so, it looks like this bug takes place for as_float method only.

Comment: is 1.#QNAN00000000000 a printf %f output?

Comment: No, it is from Watch window.

Comment: Are you sure you copy-pasted the code right? Shouldn't it be `auto i = data.begin();`?

Comment: Yes, you right, original code is more complex, I just removed extra steps to simplify it; but the fact is, for any reason it thinks that 'Id' is "NaN" instead of 0.

Comment: Then can you please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Sure, I created a small piece of code now that gives this problem (with wrong zero parsing). It is compiled with Visual C++ 2012 (it is supposed that libJSON 7 is added to project dependencies).

Comment: Have you typedeffed json_string correctly and/or defined JSON_STRING_HEADER? As far as I can see, `libjson::parse` expects a json_string. "If you change this option and are using the C++ interface, then you must recompile the entire
library because this makes a dynamic dependency that your IDE or compiler will not pick up on." (Documentation) - One more thing: did you try to debug the variables? What gives `i->dump()`?

Comment: Library is part of Visual Studio solution where this code is located, i. e. they are built togeather always. I use #define JSON_UNICODE, so libJSON is compatible with wstring in such configuration; also, if it is about encoding issues, it has to be unable to parse integers and strings, but it can not parse specifically floating point numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing a bit here, since you don't show all the relevant code:

Your json structure is `data`, `json` seems to be the string you are parsing. So `json.begin()` would be the first character in that string, not the first json value. Since that first character is double quote, it cannot be parsed as a float -> you get the nonsense you see. Maybe this is what you want:

```
JSONNode data = libjson::parse(json);
auto i = data.begin();  //<-- data, not json!
auto num = i->as_float();
```

Please remember to give all the relevant code next time, that includes definition of all used variables (in this case, 'json').

PS: The json string you posted ends with an unmatched `}` - that might confuse the parser.

Comment: Hi, it is just my spelling error (with '{'), I reposted code that compiles well and doesn't contain error in JSON. Without '{' libJSON 7 will most probably throw exception during parse call. The same with json/data. It is part of a very big project, I copied & pasted this piece of code without enough attention. Now I fixed code, so it is realistic.